# Indirect Function returns #REF

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I am trying to use a match/indirect function to find a specific value for a range of cells on a separate sheet in excel. The A3 value is the sheet number that the function is referencing and the '1' again the sheet it is referencing.

The `F1:F4000` is the range from the other sheet and the >7.5 is because I am looking for the first value above 7.5 in that range. Here is what I have so far:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT($A3&"!'1'!F1:F4000">7.5,0),
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't have two references to the sheet. You have A3 and '1' - what's the actual sheet name - what's in A3?

Comment: The actual sheet name is 1, and in cell A3 it is simply 1. It is referencing back to Sheet 1. I realize now that I cannot double reference the sheet but what about this:

'=MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT($A3&!$F1:$F4000>7.5),0),0)'

Comment: Try this `=MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT("'"&$A3&"'!F1:F4000")>7.5,0)` - formula needs to be "array entered" with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: @barryhoudini: Write up an answer...

Answer (score 2):

`=MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT("'"&$A3&"'!F1:F4000")>7.5,0)`

As this is an array function, it must be entered with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER.
I "stole" @barry hourdini's answer because this is 2 and a half months old and still on unanswered section....